# Product of nonnegative, nonconstant i.i.d. random variables with mean $1$ goes to $0$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> $X_i$ are nonnegative i.i.d. r.v's with $EX_i = 1, P(X_i \ne 1) > 0$. Show that $$Y_n = \prod_{i = 1}^n \ X_i \to 0 \qquad \text{a.s.}$$
>   By the way, the original text is "i.i.d.", but I feel that "independent" may be enough.

Can anyone show an elegant way to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true, by Kakutani's product martingale theorem. Here $Y_n$ is a martingale. According to this theorem, if $a_i:=\mathbb E\left[\sqrt{X_i}\right]$ are such that $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i>0$$ then $Y_n \to Y_{\infty}$ a.s. with $\mathbb E[Y_{\infty}]=1$. Otherwise it is true.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, Jimmy R. You are pointing to the right direction. Since I have not learnt Kakutani's product martingale theorem, it will take some time for me to understand your answer. The problem does come from a lecture note after dicussion of martingales.

Comment: If you search this keyword on the internet you will find a proof. But it is not trivial (or immediate) and I do not know of a simpler one.